# How to get a single value from gae ndb query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gql

I'm using Google App Engine with ndb backend and I want to get a single value ex: `int` from the ndb entity, after any query I get the whole entity with a projection, in my case I have a Transactions entity and I want to sum the amount properties.

What I'm using now is list comprehension on the query result like:

```
query = ndb.gql("select amount from Transactions").fetch()
result = sum([x.amount for x in query])
```

Is there any way to make ndb query returns a list of amounts only, so, I can sum the query result directly like:

```
query = ndb.gql("select amount from Transactions").fetch()
result = sum(query)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't possible

Comment: not even a simpler way than mine ?
i mean what if i have a hundreds of that entity what to do ??!

Comment: Just a note `query` in your code above is in a fact a list of entities and not a query object.  So you could reduce the above to `result = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda x: x.amount, Transactions.query().fetch(
    projection=[Transactions.amount,])))`  though far less readable than the example below.

Comment: that was helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to get list of values from projection fetch (I suppose you are looking for ndb analog of django orm Transactions.query().all().values()), you may do as follows:

```
result = sum([x.amount for x in Transactions.query().fetch(
    projection=[Transactions.amount,])])
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries